# How to change breakpoint for mobile menu toggle in Underscores theme

Tags: wordpress, togglebutton, underscores-wp

I am using the Underscores WordPress theme and currently the toggle for the mobile menu displays at 600px and smaller. But I'd like to change that to a larger screen size. I can't figure out how to change that. I'd like to change the name from "Primary Menu" to something different. No help in the Underscores documentation.

Answer (score 1):

On line 594 of style.css you will find:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .main-navigation ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Change the '37.5em' into the disired value ('800px' for example).